# Scaling an Address Form on Resize

Tags: java, forms, layout, swt, window-resize

My application has a form for filling in the names and addresses of a donor. Each donor gets a closable tab and each tab has an address form.

The problem is that the application runs in a regular application window and therefore gets scaled to all different sizes. If I make the width and height of the text fields static, they all stay in the upper left of the window on a big screen. If I make them dynamic, the form looks bad because of massive boxes for relatively small amounts of text (i.e. first name). If I space them out dynamically, I end up with large gaps in between the boxes.

What is the best way to deal with this issue? Is there a UI construct normally used for this (so far the only one I've seen used has been to put the form in a non-scalable modal dialog, which I can't do because of the tab-based UI).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion- an easy way out, taken by lots of web designers *(I know your app is not browser-based):

Constrain the content to a fixed size (e.g. 800px), and center that box horizontally.  If the user maximizes their window, they see the 800px content centered with large empty gaps to right and left.

IMHO, this is not the best, but it doesn't look as bad as if it were packed into the upper left.

This is a graphic design question, not so much about the technology...